# Split multiple count using in mysql with same table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a query in below format:

```
SELECT ETM.etm_Taxonomy, COUNT( PE.pp_profileID ) AS total_counts
FROM expertise_taxonomymaster AS ETM
LEFT JOIN expertise_taxonomy AS ET ON ETM.etm_ID = ET.`et_Taxonomy`
LEFT JOIN expertise AS E ON E.et_Taxonomy = ET.`et_ID`
LEFT JOIN profile_expertise AS PE ON PE.pp_expertiseID = E.et_ID
WHERE PE.pp_profileID IN (    
        SELECT PJ.pj_profileID
        FROM jobtitle_taxonomymaster AS JTM
        LEFT JOIN jobtitle_taxonomy AS JT ON JTM.jtm_ID = JT.`jt_Taxonomy`
        LEFT JOIN jobtitle AS J ON J.jt_taxonomy = JT.`jt_ID`
        LEFT JOIN profile_jobtitle AS PJ ON PJ.pj_jobtitleID = J.jt_ID
        WHERE JTM.jtm_Taxonomy = 'Associate'
            OR JTM.jtm_Taxonomy = 'Partner' 
        )
    AND et_lawfirmID in (195,196)
GROUP BY etm_Taxonomy
```

And I have results as follows:

```
etm_Taxonomy    total_counts
Advertising       18
Antitrust         47    
Banking          258
```

But I need below results, Count should be split based on the `JTM.ttm_Taxonomy` field

```
etm_Taxonomy    Patners195  Partners196     Associates195   Associates196
Advertising       18          18              18              18
Antitrust         47          47              47              47
Banking          258          258            258              258
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
 SELECT ETM.etm_Taxonomy, 
   SUM (CASE WHEN PJ_TAX.jtm_Taxonomy = 'Associate' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Associates,
   SUM (CASE WHEN PJ_TAX.jtm_Taxonomy = 'Partner' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Partners,
   SUM (CASE WHEN PJ_TAX.jtm_Taxonomy = 'Consultant' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Consultants,
   SUM (CASE WHEN PJ_TAX.jtm_Taxonomy = 'Counsel' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Counsels,
 COUNT(PE.pp_profileID ) AS total_counts
FROM expertise_taxonomymaster AS ETM
LEFT JOIN expertise_taxonomy AS ET ON ETM.etm_ID = ET.`et_Taxonomy`
LEFT JOIN expertise AS E ON E.et_Taxonomy = ET.`et_ID`
LEFT JOIN profile_expertise AS PE ON PE.pp_expertiseID = E.et_ID
INNER JOIN
 (
SELECT DISTINCT PJ.pj_profileID,JTM.jtm_Taxonomy
FROM jobtitle_taxonomymaster AS JTM
LEFT JOIN jobtitle_taxonomy AS JT ON JTM.jtm_ID = JT.`jt_Taxonomy`
LEFT JOIN jobtitle AS J ON J.jt_taxonomy = JT.`jt_ID`
LEFT JOIN profile_jobtitle AS PJ ON PJ.pj_jobtitleID = J.jt_ID
WHERE JTM.jtm_Taxonomy = 'Associate'
OR JTM.jtm_Taxonomy = 'Partner'
OR JTM.jtm_Taxonomy = 'Consultant'
OR JTM.jtm_Taxonomy = 'Counsel'
) as PJ_TAX
ON  PE.pp_profileID= PJ_TAX.pj_profileID
WHERE et_lawfirmID =195
GROUP BY etm_Taxonomy
```

Comment: Thanks @alex, it works. but i need to give DISTINCT for pj_profileID. Where i can add the DISTINCT?

Comment: I think DISTINCT is not working. it also show duplicates in count

Comment: it is very difficult to debug without slqfiddle. Could you provide some?

Comment: Sorry @alex, it has large data and multiple connections so leave that distinction. i have another doubt. if suppose i will give like  `WHERE et_lawfirmID in (195,196)`. in this case i need to show the count by each et_lawfirmID is there possible

Comment: Could you update your original post with new additional query result you have and expected result you need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75265/discussion-between-satheesh-and-alex).

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Your left outer joins are no outer joins really, because in your WHERE clause you say you want certain ETs and PEs only.

Mainly you want to join everything, then see whether partner or associate and whether 195 or 196 and count accordingly. This can be done with a CASE construct inside COUNT. Only problem may be duplicates leading to incorrect counts. Im am not completely sure about your database structure. In case there can be duplicate profileIDs with your inner query, you need a derived query with distinct, rather than just joining everything directly. Check if this works for you:

```
select 
  etm.etm_taxonomy, 
  count(case when t.jtm_taxonomy = 'Partner' and et_lawfirmid = 195 then 1 end) as patners195,
  count(case when t.jtm_taxonomy = 'Partner' and et_lawfirmid = 196 then 1 end) as patners196,
  count(case when t.jtm_taxonomy = 'Associate' and et_lawfirmid = 195 then 1 end) as associates195,
  count(case when t.jtm_taxonomy = 'Associate' and et_lawfirmid = 196 then 1 end) as associates196
from expertise_taxonomymaster as etm
join expertise_taxonomy as et on etm.etm_id = et.et_taxonomy
join expertise as e on e.et_taxonomy = et.et_id
join profile_expertise as pe on pe.pp_expertiseid = e.et_id
join
(
  select distinct pj.pj_profileid, jtm.jtm_taxonomy
  from jobtitle_taxonomymaster as jtm
  join jobtitle_taxonomy as jt on jtm.jtm_id = jt.jt_taxonomy
  join jobtitle as j on j.jt_taxonomy = jt.jt_id
  join profile_jobtitle as pj on pj.pj_jobtitleid = j.jt_id
  where jtm.jtm_taxonomy in ('Associate', 'Partner')
) as t on t.pj_profileid = pe.pp_profileid
where et.et_lawfirmid in (195,196);
group by etm.etm_taxonomy;
```

Comment: Thanks @thorsten. and i need to add one more, please advise me is that make sense.  `join expertise as e on e.et_taxonomy = et.et_id` in that line  can i add or condition like `join expertise as e on (e.et_taxonomy = et.et_id) or (e.et_taxonomy1 = et.et_id) or (e.et_taxonomy2 = et.et_id)`

Comment: It's possible, but you of course the sums will likely be higher, as you don't only add up all profiles for et_taxonomy, but also for et_taxonomy1 and 2. This new ON clause can also be written as `join expertise as e on et.et_id in (e.et_taxonomy, e.et_taxonomy1, e.et_taxonomy2)`.